# Connection to MySql with Node JS and Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

When I try to connect from node to my MySql database that runs on the same machine (debian), with a specific user and password I get an "Access denied" error.
If I try the same, with the same user and set no password in the database and node, everything works.

Also connection from the terminal WITH password works fine.
I already tried to delete user and database and recreated them. But nothing works.

This is my node code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')
var sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql://user:password@localhost:3306/databasename');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.dir(req.url);
    sequelize.query("SELECT @@version;").spread(function(results, metadata) {
        console.log(results);
    })

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

    res.end('ok');
}).listen(8080);
```

What I get on the console is this:

```
Possibly unhandled Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:30:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:67:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:197:24)
    at Parser.write (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:62:12)
    at Protocol.write (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:37:16)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:555:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:110:26)
    at Protocol.handshake (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:42:41)
    at Connection.connect (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:81:18)
    at ConnectorManager.connect (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connector-manager.js:314:16)
    at Object.create (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connector-manager.js:138:19)
    at createResource (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:258:13)
    at dispense (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:250:9)
    at Object.me.acquire (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:316:5)
    at CustomEventEmitter.fct (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connector-manager.js:248:19)
    at CustomEventEmitter.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/sequelize/lib/emitters/custom-event-emitter.js:24:18)
```

Any clues?

Comment: Does the password contain characters that may cause issues with used in an URI like that? Percent signs, ampersands, plus-signs, etc.

Comment: No, nothing like that. I tried the same with mysqljs and get the same error...

Comment: So `mysql -uuser -p databasename` works (after entering the password)?

Comment: yes. that works fine. Connecting without user works to. Just user + password fails.

Comment: Strange. The only think I can recommend is to try connecting using separate arguments (documented [here](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/getting-started/), under _"Setting up a connection"_).

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. I added the port and everything I found as solution. But nothing works. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was, package.json did not contain the dependency (mysql or sequelize). I still don't know, why I could connect to the database without password though.
But now it works.